# How to combine vue-cli development mode with server-side api?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-router

I'm new to vue and kind of confuse here.

I'm using vue-cli to build a vue app, I understand I can run a development server with `npm run serve` which is referenced as a script in my package.json for `vue-cli-service serve`

But my app need some data coming from a local node.js server. I cannot request this server from development mode because it's running on a different server.
To make my app work I'm obligated to build for production with

```
npm run build
```

Then to ask my node server to render by default the produced index.html file.

How could I combine development mode and my node server?

What would be the best way to make this work?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you get any errors? What port are you running your node server on? I'd be willing to bet it's port related - what you're trying to do IS possible..

Comment: Same ip but different port, I get `access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/connected' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error in web browser console

Comment: You most likely need to add a `cors` library or `cors` header server side.. [Good example here](https://medium.com/@alexishevia/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b) if you're using Express..

Comment: yeah Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can simply define a proxy to solve this issue for local development: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across this, and found the answer buried at the bottom of the comments list, so I thought I'd highlight it.
This answer is taken from @Frank Provost comment, which really should be the accepted answer.   As mentioned in his link https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy all you need to do is create/edit **vue.config.js file in your (client) project root** to include this:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:3000' // enter dev server url here 
  }
}
```

Then start your dev server as usual from your server project:

```
[server-root]$ npm run dev
```

And run your client project from vue-cli project

```
[client-root]$ npm run serve
```

Then when you visit the client url (usually localhost:8080) all api requests will be forwarded to your dev server.  All hot module replacement still works on both client and server.